# Проброс значения data-атрибута при клике

Tags: html, jquery

Есть набор элементов input. Необходимо при клике на любом элементе, независимо от его типа, вывести его значение data-fname или id в поле data-debug.

Основное условие: результат обработчика должен быть доступен за пределами самого обработчика т.к. в последующем возвращённое обработчиком значение переменной используется в другом месте кода

```js
var prefix_acc = 'acc_';
var acc_id = '';
$('[id^="' + prefix_acc + '"]').click(function() {
  var acc_id = $(this).attr("id");
  return acc_id;
});
$("[data-debug]").text(acc_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-fname="number" id="acc_number"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="date" id="acc_date"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="name" id="acc_munit"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="dislt" id="acc_tlocal"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="disln" id="acc_loc"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="disla" id="acc_obl"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="objects" id="acc_objects"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="laborators" id="acc_laborators"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="types" id="acc_types"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="materials" id="acc_materials"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="study" id="acc_study">
<hr>
<div data-debug> Data-Fname / ID </div>
```

Comment: Вам важно понять, что в Вашем коде строчка `$("[data-debug]").text(acc_id);` выполнится до всяких кликов.

Comment: @Igor, тогда подскажите как мне вытянуть результат обработки в виде переменной на свет божий, чтобы использовать этот результат в дальнейшем

...третьи сутки бьюсь над этой задачкой...

Comment: так, как я это сделал в ответе. Попробуйте объяснить, что у Вас не работает, когда Вы используете код из моего ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Вы редекларируете `acc_id` внутри обработчика `click` как локальную переменную. Уберите `var` и внесите `$("[data-debug]").text(acc_id);` внутрь обработчика.

```
var prefix_acc = 'acc_';
var acc_id = '';
$('[id^="' + prefix_acc + '"]').click(function() {
  acc_id = $(this).data("fname");
  $("[data-debug]").text(acc_id);
});
```

Comment: Не работаеть(((

Comment: @WarDoctor Вы неаккуратно скопировали мой код :)

Comment: Мои извинения...

Comment: Переменная acc_id в последующем коде должна быть использована, поэтому проверка ее значения и вынесена за пределы обработчика

Comment: какая проверка? Назначается-то эта переменная внутри обработчика.

Comment: Значение переменной дается внутри обработки, а вот это значение вытащить из него и потом использовать...

Comment: @WarDoctor я уже показал, как это сделать. Что для Вас означает слово "потом"?

Comment: "потом" - у меня есть несколько функций где с этой переменной планирую делать преобразования

Comment: @WarDoctor код, который сейчас в ответе, Вас все еще не устраивает?

Comment: извините, но не в полном объеме...
такое я уж тупое и настырное

Comment: @WarDoctor Что у Вас не работает с предложенным кодом - я должен сам догадаться?

Comment: Ваш код рабочий, но основное условие обработчик должен вернуть значение переменной для последующей обработки этой переменной в другом месте программы. Поэтому и сделана проверка за пределами обработчика

Comment: так, беседа пошла по кругу.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var prefix_acc = 'acc_';
var acc_id = '';
$('[id^="' + prefix_acc + '"]').click(function() {
  var acc_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("[data-debug]").text(acc_id);
  return acc_id;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-fname="number" id="acc_number"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="date" id="acc_date"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="name" id="acc_munit"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="dislt" id="acc_tlocal"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="disln" id="acc_loc"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="disla" id="acc_obl"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="objects" id="acc_objects"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="laborators" id="acc_laborators"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="types" id="acc_types"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="materials" id="acc_materials"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="study" id="acc_study">
<hr>
<div data-debug> Data-Fname / ID </div>
```

Comment: Так работает, но мне надо использовать переменную acc_id за пределами минифункции... Поэтому $("[data-debug]").text(acc_id); установлена именно вне диапазона click

Comment: @WarDoctor Вы умышленно умолчали об этом в вопросе?

Comment: `return acc_id;` - смысл?

Comment: Код привел именно так как необходимо для его реализации в дальнейшем
переменная acc_id в дальнейшем должна быть использована, поэтому и надо ее вернуть

Comment: @Igor, кто же его знает?) Так в задаче написано, скопировано, вставлено xDD

Answer (score 0):

Блин, ну зачем тут велосипеды придумывать?
Все просто.
Конкретно в данном примере код таков (используя jQuery):

```
var $data_debug = $('[data-debug]'),
    acc_id;
$('input').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    acc_id = $this.attr('id');
    $data_debug.text($this.attr('data-fname') + ' / ' + acc_id);
});
```

А вообще лучше добавь элементам классы и по возможности не засоряй глобальное пространство, используй обертки типа `(function($){/*Код*/})(jQuery);`

Comment: ...переменная acc_id и результат обработчика должны быть доступны за пределами самого обработчика т.к. в последующем возвращённое обработчиком значение переменной используется в другом месте кода...

Answer (score 0):

Решение вопроса:

```js
var prefix_acc = 'acc_';
$(function() {
  $('[id^="' + prefix_acc + '"]').click(function() {
    var id_acc = $(this).data("fname");
    MyFunction(id_acc);
  });

  function MyFunction(inp_id) {
    //код выполнения
    $("[data-debug]").text(inp_id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-fname="number" id="acc_number"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="date" id="acc_date"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="name" id="acc_munit"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="dislt" id="acc_tlocal"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="disln" id="acc_loc"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="disla" id="acc_obl"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="objects" id="acc_objects"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="laborators" id="acc_laborators"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="types" id="acc_types"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="materials" id="acc_materials"><br>
<input type="text" data-fname="study" id="acc_study">
<hr>
<div data-debug> Data-Fname / ID </div>
```

Всем спасибо за помощь. Ещё раз мои извинения за мой тупизм.
Переменную надо было не сохранять как внешнюю, а передать как параметр в функцию для последующей обработки, включив имя функции в обработчик.